# JQuery Dynamic Class Rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to figure out how to do a form validation using jquery on dynamically created fields.

The example:

```
<input type="text" name="field_1" class="validminmax"><input type="hidden" name="field_1_min" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="field_1_max" value="10">

<input type="text" name="field_2" class="validminmax"><input type="hidden" name="field_2_min" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="field_2_max" value="10">

<input type="text" name="field_3" class="validminmax"><input type="hidden" name="field_3_min" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="field_3_max" value="10">
```

....

In the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $.validator.addClassRules({
      validminmax:{
         required:true,
         number: true,
     minValue: ???,
     maxValue: ???
    }
    });
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to appropriately use the minValue and maxValue with those other fields (field_**min, field**_max).

So every field_* I would like the corresponding min and max fields applied.  Is there  anyway I could do that?  There are probably better ways to do it than I have currently coded it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is use the rule 'range', which can be applied as a class rule like below

```
<input type="text" id="x" name="x" class="range" min="1" max="9"/>
```